# stripping strings between a comma in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I know to do parts of it but not all of it, lets say my table name is REV and column name is DESCR and it has a value like

```
R&B , Semiprivate 2 Beds , Medical/Surgical/GYN
```

i use

```
SELECT  DESCR, LEFT(DESCR, Charindex(',', DESCR)),  SUBSTRING(DESCR, CHARINDEX(',', DESCR) + 1, LEN(DESCR)) from REV
```

i get 'R&B ,' in one column and 'Semiprivate 2 Beds , Medical/Surgical/GYN' in another column in the above select statement but i dont know how to selesct the strings from teh second comma onwards

what i like to return is 'R&B' in one column without the comma and 'Semiprivate 2 Beds' in another column and 'Medical/Surgical/GYN' so on

basically select test between commas and when there is no comma it should be blank

Comment: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings - This is a very common kind of question and Aaron Bertrand has published about this multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
  LEFT(DESCR, CHARINDEX(',', DESCR)-1), 
  SUBSTRING(DESCR, CHARINDEX(',', DESCR)+1, LEN(DESCR)-CHARINDEX(',', DESCR)-CHARINDEX(',',REVERSE(DESCR ))),
  RIGHT(DESCR, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(DESCR))-1)  
FROM REV
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/73f63/1)

This will split the string, but leave blank at the beginning and end of the strings, you can use `LTRIM`and `RTRIM`to trim away the blanks.

There might be better ways to do this though; see the article [Split strings the right way – or the next best way](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) by Aaron Bertrand at (that Andrew mentioned in a comment).

Comment: The 1st and 3rd column in the select works but the middle column is not extracting it correctly it seems to be breaking. e.g: 'Hospital, Swing Beds, Interim-First Claim' comes out as 'Hospital' and 'Swing beds, Interi' and 'Interim-First Claim'. the second column is not coming out correclty

Comment: @user176047 I made some changes and added a sample SQL Fiddle. It should be more correct now, but it will only handle a string with two commas and split it into three parts.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
  SELECT 
  LEFT(DESCR, CHARINDEX(',', DESCR)-1), 
  SUBSTRING(DESCR, CHARINDEX(',', DESCR)+1, CHARINDEX(',', DESCR, CHARINDEX(',', DESCR)+1) -  CHARINDEX(',', DESCR) -1 ),
  RIGHT(DESCR, CHARINDEX(',', REVERSE(DESCR))-1)
  FROM REV
```